# I have survey data with responses are encoded in numbers and the actual datamap file where the code number & actual value is present in another file

Tags: sql, database, nosql, analysis, survey

I have survey data with responses are encoded in numbers and the actual datamap file where the code number & actual value is present in another file. I want to analyse this data how to combine this data in order to make sense out of it.

I am not getting where to do it in SQL or NoSql and how to do that.if any idea anyone can share it would be very helpful. Data snapshot please check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNo4J.png)

Comment: We'd probably need to see examples of the data to make good suggestions.  You tagged / mention databases.  Is your goal to import this data into a database?

Comment: @erik258 have attached snapshot for data kindly check